# ReactCssTransitionGroup not fading in

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm building a personal site w/ React and trying to get some h2's to fade in after a couple of seconds after load. I'm using ReactCssTransitionGroup on the following Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

class TitleArea extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ids: ['h2-one', 'h2-two', 'h2-three'],
      h2Texts: ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3']
    };
  }

  render() {
    const descriptionDivs = this.state.ids.map( (id, index)=> {
      return(<h2 key={id} id={id}>
        {this.state.h2Texts[index]}
      </h2>)
    })
return (
  <div className='row odd'>
    <h1> MYNAMEHERE </h1>
    <div className='description-container'>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
      transitionName="descriptions"
      transitionEnterTimeout={500}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
        {descriptionDivs}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>
  </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TitleArea;
```

CSS/SASS:

```
.site-container {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
   }
  }
.descriptions-enter {
   opacity: 0.01;
 }
.descriptions-enter.descriptions-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
 }
```

I'd ideally want each h2 to transition in one after another, but I'm trying to get a handle on the react-addons  first before I jump to staggering the fade-ins. Does anyone have any experience with css transitions in React. Tried following the docs but got a bit lost. Any insight greatly appreciated! Thanks